# create c++ vector with variable dimension number

Tags: c++

I m trying to create a vector with not known number of dimensions at compile time.

i found here some topics talking on the same subject but didn't answered my case like [Create n-dimensional vector with given sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995642/create-n-dimensional-vector-with-given-sizes/29995795#29995795) and [C++: generate multidimensional vector of unknown depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48456507/c-generate-multidimensional-vector-of-unknown-depth)

i could extract one working solution (compiles without errors) from first link above but i couldn't implement it.

```
template <typename T, int n>
struct NDVector {
    typedef std::vector<typename NDVector<T, n - 1>::type> type;
};

template <typename T>
struct NDVector<T, 0> {
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> make_vector_(std::size_t size) {
    return std::vector<T>(size);
}


template <typename T, typename... Args>
typename NDVector<T, sizeof...(Args) + 1>::type make_vector_(std::size_t first, Args... sizes) {
    typedef typename NDVector<T, sizeof...(Args) + 1>::type Result;
    return Result(first, make_vector_<T>(sizes...));
}
```

and create my vector variable like below

```
NDVector<int,4> myVector;
```

This is the only reasonable solution, but i couldn't push, erase, clear .... from myVector. also cannot use sub-scripting notation (myVector[x]).
the second problem here that i couldn't use variable int instead of a constant number in the declaration (change number '4' with variable).

My goal is to be able to declare the vector like that:

```
unsigned n;
NDVector<int,n> myVector;
```

and also being able to use the 'myVector' variable like normal vectors

Comment: Sorry, C++ does not work this way. The type of every object must be known at compile time. This is fundamental to C++.

Comment: *I m trying to create a vector with not known number of dimensions at compile time.* -- Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Are you trying to create a vector of vectors here ?

Comment: A template argument must be a compile time constant but I think something like can be achieved without templates using polymorphism instead.

Comment: maybe [A Class Template for N-Dimensional Generic Resizable Arrays](https://www.drdobbs.com/a-class-template-for-n-dimensional-gener/184401319) is of interest

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i know the type should be know at compile time but i want the number of dimension is unknown somthing like vector<vector<n times>> myVector.

Comment: @YoussefSbaiidrissi no. vector of vector is 2D dimensions and vector of vector of vector is 3D .... i want N dimension

Comment: @ThomasSablik it will be more helpful if u give a small piece of code as an example

Comment: @Thomas thnx for answer but the link that u gave is like the example that i said
Array<int,5> A5;   // Five-dimensional array of ints!
Array<float,1> A1; // One-dimensional array of floats?
the array size is already known (5 for a5 and 1 for a1) but i m looking for something like:
int n;
n = getTheValueOfN();
Array<int,n> A_N;

Comment: The number of dimensions is a part of a type. `vector<T>` and `vector<vector<T>>` are two different types. You must know the type at compile time. C++ does not work this way. You cannot have an object with an unknown number of dimensions, in C++.

Comment: `Array<int,n>` can't be done in c++, olnly something like `Array<int>(n)` and you would need to know the size of each dimension, so prob. more like ``Array<int>( d1,d2,..,dn )`.

Comment: found [lite array - A C++ Multidimensional Array Library](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~saeed/lite/html/group__array.html), that seems pretty close

Answer (score 2):

That’s actually way simpler that a compile-time solution.

Your class needs to store two vectors: one for bounds (as their count is unknown at compile time) and another for actual data (so its size is bounds[0]*...*bounds[dim-1]).

Then it needs the subscription operator, or get/set functions. As the dimensionality is not know yet, they need to accept an array of indices, not a fixed count of arguments. Vector is perfectly suitable. Given that, it can calculate the index in the internal array, and return a reference to that particular element.

Then you may try to handle all the sort of `resize` pain. Or just don’t promise to keep any data on resize.